# Extracting Number and Name from String [r]

Tags: regex, r, string, text-extraction

POSIX Expression is giving me a headache.

Lets say we have a string:

```
a = "[question(37), question_pipe(\"Person10\")]"
```

and ultimately I would like to be able to have:

```
b = c("37", "Person10")
```

I've had a look at the `stringr` package but cant figure out how to extract the information out using regular expressions and `str_split`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cameron

Comment: Do all lines have this format?

Comment: Yes but the content may be different, ie '"[question(37), question_pipe(\"Cam B\")]"' 

It's extracted from JSON data from surveygizmo response data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to extract the elements within parenthesis.

You can first extract those elements, including the parenthesis,  using `str_extract_all`:

```
b1 <- str_extract_all(string = a, pattern = "\\(.*?\\)")
b1
# [[1]]
# [1] "(37)"           "(\"Person10\")"
```

Since `str_extract_all` returns a list, let's turn it into a vector:

```
b2 <- unlist(b1)
b2
# [1] "(37)"           "(\"Person10\")"
```

Last, you can remove the parenthesis (the first and last character of each string) using `str_sub`:

```
b3 <- str_sub(string = b2, start = 2L, end = -2L) 
b3
# [1] "37"           "\"Person10\""
```

Edit: A few comments about the regex pattern: `\\(` and `\\)` are your opening and closing parenthesis. `.*?` means any character string but without being greedy, otherwise you would get one long match from the first `(` to the last `)`.

Comment: This will work for me, thanks. But how would you remove the "\" as well as the extra " from the end from person10?

Comment: Ah got it `gsub("\"", "", b3)` Thanks for your help flodel :)

Comment: this is more concise: b1 <- unlist(str_extract_all(string = a, pattern = "\\(.*?\\)"));
b <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", b1)

Answer (score 3):

This should work in you specific case:

```
a <- "[question(37), question_pipe(\"Person10\")]"

# First split into two parts
b <- strsplit(a, ",")[[1]]

# Extract the number (skip as.integer if you want it as character)
x <- as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]","", b[[1]])) # 37

# Extract the stuff in quotes
y <- gsub(".*\"(.*)\".*", "\\1", b[[2]])   # "Person10"
```

An alternative for extracting everything in parentheses from the first part:

```
x <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", b[[1]]) # "37"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
a <- "[question(37), question_pipe(\"Person10\")]"
b <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("\"","",gsub(".*question\\((.*)\\).*question_pipe\\((.*)\\).*","\\1,\\2",a)),","))
print(b)
[1] "37"       "Person10"
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on flodel's answer -
this would be the most concise solution, i think:

```
a <- "[question(37), question_pipe(\"Person10\")]"    
b1 <- unlist(str_extract_all(string = a, pattern = "\(.*?\)"))
b <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", b1)
```