# R extract numbers from a string

Tags: r

string would be

```
"-042-195" "+143-192" "-001*145" "#045+125" "#125$"
```

How do I extract the last set of numbers?

```
"195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting Number and Name from String \[r\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796752/extracting-number-and-name-from-string-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 v1 <- c("-042-195","+143-192","-001*145", "#045+125", "#125$")
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(v1, perl("(?<=[^0-9])[0-9]+(?=[^0-9]?$)"))
 #[1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

#### Explanation

```
 (?<=[^0-9]) #look behind for all except numbers
 [0-9]+ #followed by numbers
 (?=[^0-9]?$ #look ahead for all except numbers if present near the end
```

Or

```
  sapply(str_extract_all(v1, "\\d+"),tail,1)
 #[1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

Or

```
 library(stringi)
  stri_extract_last(v1,regex="\\d+")
 #[1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably better ways but you can `strsplit` and then take the last element of the result

```
> sapply(strsplit(myData, "-|[*]|[+]|#|[$]"), tail, n = 1)
[1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

or replace all non alpha-numeric characters and then split and take last numbers

```
> sapply(strsplit(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "&", myData), "&"), tail, n = 1)
[1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) sub** If `ch` is the input vector of character strings then use `sub` with a regular expression matching anything up to a non-digit (`"\\D"`) followed by the digits (`"\\d+"`) followed by anything else (`".*"`) and return the matched digits:

```
sub(".*\\D(\\d+).*", "\\1", paste(" ", ch))
## [1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

If we were guaranteed that the numerics are preceeded by at least one non-numeric, which is the case for the example in the question, then `paste(" ", ch)` could be simplified to just `ch`:

```
sub(".*\\D(\\d+).*", "\\1", ch) 
## [1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

**2) strapplyc**  `strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) matches the indicated regular expression allowing a simpler regular expression than above:

```
library(gsubfn)

sapply(strapplyc(ch, "\\d+"), tail, 1)
## [1] "195" "192" "145" "125" "125"
```

**2a) strapply** or use `strapply` (no `c` at the end) with `as.numeric` to return numbers:

```
sapply(strapply(ch, "\\d+", as.numeric), tail, 1)
## [1] 195 192 145 125 125
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like piling on, but this works on the given sample:

```
v1 <- c("-042-195","+143-192","-001*145", "#045+125", "#125$")
v1 <- gsub("\\D", "", v1)
v1 <- substr(x = v1, start = nchar(v1)-2, nchar(v1))
```

`Gsub` out everything but digits, then call `substr` to keep the final three digits