# extracting numbers from string in R using a template

Tags: r, scanf, stringr

I want to automatically extract Totals and percentages reported in this document https://health-infobase.canada.ca/covid-19/epidemiological-summary-covid-19-cases.html in Table 2 and Figure 7.
They are printed there as `16,296 (12.4%)`

Can you help me please to write an R function that does this, i.e., which gets two numbers `A` and `B from a string` A (B%)`.

Note there are "," in large numbers.

Thank you

Comment: found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595515/r-extract-numbers-from-a-string. Looking for the simplest answer - something similar to `scanf` in C

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to come up with a general solution with only one example but here is my attempt. You have also not shared how is this data stored in R environment but I'll assume this is a string.

```
x <- '16,296 (12.4%)'
num1 <- readr::parse_number(x)
num2 <- as.numeric(sub('.*\\((\\d+\\.\\d+)\\%\\).*', '\\1', x))

num1
#[1] 16296

num2
#[1] 12.4
```

where `readr::parse_number` returns the first numeric value and output of `sub` is a number in parenthesis (`(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
x <- '16,296 (12.4%)'

library(magrittr)
#gsub to remove (, ), % and comma.
#split on space, unlisted and convert to number
gsub("[(),%]", "", x) %>% strsplit(" ") %>% unlist() %>% as.numeric()
```